# Smooth complex projective surface as the total space of a Serre fibration

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, homotopy-theory, differential-topology

Let $M$ be the underlying topological manifold of a smooth complex projective surface. Assume $\pi_1(M)=\{0\}$ and $\pi_2(M)\neq \mathbb{Z}^2$.

Is there a Serre fibration $M\to B$ where $B$ is a CW complex of dimension $0<d<4$?

Comment: I think you can exclude d=1,3 from the euler characteristic. At least if this is required to be a fibration of manifolds.

Comment: Why is the question changed dramatically?

Answer (score 9):

I don't think so.  (There are the exceptions you mention: the two $S^2$ bundles over $S^2$.) By Thomas's comment, let's assume that d = 2.

If M is a fibration of a manifold with finite complexes for base and fiber, then the base and fiber are Poincare duality spaces (Gottlieb, PAMS 1979). Hence in this dimension, they are surfaces. Since your M is simply connected, the base must be a 2-sphere. But then you can conclude from the long exact sequence of the fibration that the fiber is a 2-sphere as well.

Comment: we don't assume that the fiber is a CW complex

Comment: @JoeT What are the circumstances where you might have such a fibration (ie with non-CW complex fiber)? Maybe you could give some more context for your question.

Comment: I don't know, I just got curious if there could be such a fibration (seeing as the fiber is strictly speaking not a part of the data of a fibration)